# why do the sum of numbers follow the results from before?

Tags: c

```
printf("The number of cases: ");
scanf("%d", &t);
for(i = 1; i <= t; i++){
scanf("%d", &n);
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        scanf("%d", &h);
        sum = sum + h;
        
    }
    printf("Case #%d: %d\n", i, sum);
}
```

...
i have some problem with this code to find a total of sum
when i using "for loop".
why the results of the next case follow the results from the previous one?
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never clear out the value of `sum` after the inner loop runs, so you keep adding to the sum.

Set `sum` to 0 before entering the inner loop.

```
for(i = 1; i <= t; i++){
    scanf("%d", &n);
    sum = 0;
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        scanf("%d", &h);
        sum = sum + h;
        
    }
    printf("Case #%d: %d\n", i, sum);
}
```